# Use selenium to grab elements with random strings?

Tags: python, selenium

What I'm trying to do: Use selenium with python to grab reddit root comments (AKA comments that aren't replying to anyone).

My Question:
How can I refer to the class names if they're random strings, as shown in the screenshot.

[Inspect element screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rN3vM.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can use below solutions :

**ID :**

```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(
                        EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "t1_fmun119")))
```

**Xpath :**

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(
                EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[@id='t1_fmun119']")))
```

**Note :** please add below imports to your solution

```
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
```

Comment: Sorry I don't think my question was clear enough. I want to get every root comment, not just one element by that exact ID (t1_fmun119). Each root comment has a random string as its ID, so how would i grab them?

Comment: If you post your url or DOM structure then may be siblings will help to extract xpath for you